# Function statement being called 1+ times after AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is an odd title, but I'm not sure how to describe what's happening.

Basically, I have the following code which runs after an AJAX request is made:

```
if (doAjax) {
    $("#loading").removeClass("visible");
    $("#loading").addClass("hidden");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#loading").css({
            "display": "none",
            "opacity": "0",
        });
    }, 300);
    if (number.length === 0) {
        $("#nothing").css("display", "inline-table");
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#nothing").addClass("visible");
        }, 1);
    } else {
        setFavorite();
        checkFavorite();
    }
}
```

If the AJAX request returns results, then it will run the `setFavorite();` and `checkFavorite();` functions once it completed. I also have the ability to reload the AJAX request when clicking a button, which would then also run those functions at the end of the request.

Problem is, if the user loads the page, it will run the AJAX, and will be fine. If the user **calls** the AJAX request again, however, the function is ran twice. If it is called once more, it is ran three times.

**So**, each time the AJAX request is made, the number of times `setFavorite();` and `checkFavorite();` are called increases by one.

I confirmed this by placing an `alert` within `setFavorite()` to see why it was calling so randomly, and it would always be called x number of times where x is the number of times the user has reloaded the AJAX request.

If needed, I will post the `setFavorite();` and `checkFavorite();` functions, but I feel like the error lies within the `doAjax` function.

**Edit 1**

Reload function:

```
function reload(){
    doAjax("http://www.codekraken.com/testing/snowday/wgrz.html");
};

$("#reload").click(reload);
```

**Edit duo**

`doAjax();`

```
function doAjax(url) {
    $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22" + encodeURIComponent(url) + "%22&format=xml'&callback=?",
    function (data) {
        if (data.results[0]) {
            $("#content").html("");
            var number = $(filterData(data.results[0])).find("#gtv_leftcolumn table:gt(1)");
            for (var i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
                var school = $(filterData(data.results[0])).find("#gtv_leftcolumn table:gt(1) .maintext p:eq(" + i + ")").text();
                var type = $(filterData(data.results[0])).find("#gtv_leftcolumn table:gt(1) .trafficbriefs:nth-child(even) p:eq(" + i + ")").text();
                $("#content").append("<div class='row'><div class='row-inside'><div class='row-l'>" + school + "</div><div class='row-r'>" + type + "</div></div><div class='star'><div class='star-inside'></div></div></div>");
            };
            if (doAjax) {
                $("#loading").removeClass("visible");
                $("#loading").addClass("hidden");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#loading").css({
                        "display": "none",
                        "opacity": "0",
                    });
                }, 300);
                if (number.length === 0) {
                    $("#nothing").css("display", "inline-table");
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $("#nothing").addClass("visible");
                    }, 1);
                } else {
                    setFavorite();
                    checkFavorite();
                }
            }
        } else {
            console.log("error");
        }
    })
}

function filterData(data) {
    data = data.replace(/<?\/body[^>]*>/g, '');
    data = data.replace(/[\r|\n]+/g, '');
    data = data.replace(/<--[\S\s]*?-->/g, '');
    data = data.replace(/<noscript[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/noscript>/g, '');
    data = data.replace(/<script[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/script>/g, '');
    data = data.replace(/<script.*\/>/, '');
    data = data.replace(/<img[^>]*>/g, '');
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Where's the AJAX call? Hard for me to picture what's going on without knowing how this is interacting with AJAX. But @Dcullen seems to be on the money

Comment: The AJAX call is within document ready, which looks like this: `doAjax("url");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like you are binding the reload button every time the function is ran.  Which will run the function multiple times.

Are you able to show the setFavorite(); and checkFavorite(); functions?

If you have to rebind the button every reload you can unbind the button before rebinding.

Comment: I edited my question with the reload function. Let me know if you still want to see the `setFavorite();` and `checkFavorite();` functions.

Comment: Can you try and add an alert inside the reload function to see if it has the same increment issue.  That should either prove or un-prove the binding theory.

Comment: After adding an alert into the reload function, it is only displaying the alert once.

Comment: Cool, proven wrong.  Next thing would be to see the doAjax function if possible.  Don't want to make another wrong guess.

Comment: It's a lengthy one, I'll post it into the question.

Comment: Just went through it.  Can't seem to see the issue at a glance.  Next question would be to see how often the response gets called. Adding an alert/console log after "function (data) {"

Comment: Just tried, only running if either a.) the page loads or b.) the reload button is pressed. When the reload button is pressed, it only loads it once.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't reproduce when I try and recreate the issue.  http://jsfiddle.net/vh8ep/  Sorry I couldn't help!

Comment: setFavorite() looks like it only needs to run once onLoad.  The binds will stay after each ajax call due to you adding them to the window object.  Everytime you run that function you are rebinding the touch events with "addEventListener".  If you need to run it each time use window.removeEventListener on each of the events for each ajax call.

Comment: Moving `setFavorite()` to just run onLoad, and keeping `setFavorite()` where it currently is works perfectly. Thank you for the help @Dcullen